# SSL VPN by java can't stop loading

Tags: java, ssl

When I use a product which relies on Java, It can't stop loading.

What's the meaning of 'relogin task cms register failed!'?

Why it says 'Please install Java!'?

My web browser is pale moon which supports Java;

My system is Debian 9;

Here is the partial content of java console：

```
13:25:34 [task] relogin task start.
13:25:34 [task] relogin task cms register failed!
13:25:34 [api] query service cmd = QUERY INSTALLMODULE SERVICE.
13:25:34 [mainthd] task thread is alive and onwork.
13:25:34 [task] controls installed task start.
13:25:34 [task] controls installed task finished, result = true.
13:25:34 [api] query service cmd = QUERY INSTALLMODULE SERVICE.
13:25:34 [mainthd] task thread is alive and onwork.
13:25:34 [task] controls installed task start.
13:25:34 [task] controls installed task finished, result = true.
13:25:34 [api] start service.
13:25:34 [mainthd] task thread is alive and onwork.
13:25:34 [task] controls installed task start.
13:25:34 [task] controls installed task finished, result = true.
13:25:34 [mainthd] main thread start to init.
13:25:34 [api] query service cmd = QUERY QSETTING RCERTINFO.
13:25:34 [mainthd] task thread is alive and onwork.
13:25:34 [mainthd] main thread start to work.
13:25:34 [cstartup] cstartup thread start.
13:25:34 [sockthd] socket thread start.
13:25:34 [sockthd] no port, try again after 800ms.
13:25:35 Please install Java!
13:25:35 [cstartup] cstartup thread exit with error, exit code = 2.
13:25:35 [cstartup] cstartup thread exit, status = abnormal.
13:25:35 [task] qry task start, QSETTING RCERTINFO.
13:25:36 [api] query service cmd = QUERY QSTATE ALLSERVICES.
13:25:36 [mainthd] task thread is alive and onwork.
13:25:36 [task] qry task start, QSTATE ALLSERVICES.
13:25:36 [sockthd] socket thread exit.
13:25:39 [api] query service cmd = QUERY LOGOUT.
13:25:39 [api] query service cmd = QUERY QSESSIONID.
13:25:44 [api] query service cmd = QUERY LOGOUT.
13:25:44 [api] query service cmd = QUERY QSESSIONID.
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question at all.  Rather, it sounds like you have a problem with some product that you have bought or downloaded.  You should start by contacting the people who support the product.

Comment: One thing to note is that recent releases of Java do not support Java in the web browser at all.  For example: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/firefox_java.xml.   So if you are trying to use an application that relies on Java in the browser, you should look for an alternative.  But apparently Pale Moon still supports NPAPI plugins ... https://askubuntu.com/questions/906315/install-java-plugin-in-pale-moon-browser ... but there are some tricks in getting it to recognize the plugin.

Comment: @StephenC When I test java by this [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp), I get this exception in Java console: [exception.md](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzCLPN5o3ziHczJieHlhcS16ZjA/view?usp=sharing). Besides, my question is partly solved(I didn't set the environment of Java.....).

Comment: @StephenC But, now the product  works well.

Comment: That's nice to hear.  So why were you having problems?  Did you follow the installation instructions incorrectly?  Where the instructions incomplete?  Did you contact the suppliers?  Were they helpful?

Comment: For what it it worth, since you never told us what this product is, there was almost zero chance that anyone could have helped you.  And by your own account, it is clear that this was a software installation problem and not a programming question.  Therefore it was and is off-topic.

Comment: @StephenC suppliers don't reply me. so, I tried many Java version and set Java environment again. But, the origin version works well......I don't know what happened..maybe, when I log in by ssh, waitting time is short. Now, waitting for a while, it works.

Comment: @StephenC the product is songfor which is a chinese product. Our school use it.

Comment: Ah yes.  Chinese VPN software.  We have heard about that in the west.  Nuff said.

Comment: @StephenC lol, I never pay for it. Mybe, my school pay it. My school's introduction for it is windows version. So, linux version lose their attention.

Comment: @StephenC This ssl vpn is designed for connectting to school's sever. That vpn your stuff mentioned is designed to visit some websites which china forbiden like google, youtube, twitter and so on. I bought a ramnode server to build my vpn : )